# Bootstrap center dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a dropdown menu in my nav that has three columns, that looks like this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                    <li><a href="#">test1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test1-3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                    <li><a href="#">test2-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test2-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test2-3</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                    <li><a href="#">test3-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test3-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">test3-3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It works, but when I click on the dropdown, the offset of the dropdown is where the dropdown link is. How can I center the dropdown menu instead of positioning it where the dropdown link is? As you can seen in this screenshot, the dropdown is not centered.

[image: Nav Offset Example]

Comment: You need to add some custom css to the div.container to adjust its position. This is a hard fix.

Comment: Check this out - http://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/#positioning-centered

Comment: @rageit that plugin doesn't do anything, it is still displayed the same

Comment: @TheBoogieMan I would suggest you to use Bootstrap Modal in this case, as if you have so many options, not worth repositioning it with much efforts

Answer (score 0):

This is giving me the result that I am looking for:

```
.nav > li.dropdown{ position: static; }
.nav > li.dropdown .dropdown-menu {display: none; width: 100%; left:0; right:0; }
.dropdown-menu>li { display: inline-block; }
```

I then also have this javascript for a hover effect:

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
}, function(){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
});
```